# UIButton appearance also sets keyboard buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

While I was trying to clean up some code I wanted to use appearances of views. But the `UIButton` troubles me. I tried the following:

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UIViewController class]]] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UIViewController class]]] setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This works like expected and all my buttons turned red with blue colour (in my project I used other colours). I noticed the buttons in the navigation bar also turned, which is something I rather not have so adding this line fixed this first problem:

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UINavigationBar class], [UIViewController class]]] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

But these aren't the only buttons. The keyboard buttons (the undo, redo and paste) on the iPad also have other appearances than default. Is there any way I can fix this? Also, is there a list of appearances that I can use safely without 'breaking' other views (like in this case the keyboard buttons)? I am not talking about a list off all appearances as I have found this [here](https://gist.github.com/mattt/5135521).

The idea was to select only the buttons in my `UIViewController` (which contains also the navigation bar) but apparently the keyboard is also child of the `UIViewController`. I hope there is a way without the need of adding custom views or wrappers around the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Create MyBaseViewController as a subclass to UIViewController, with an empty implementation. Change all of your viewControllers to inherit from MyBaseViewController. Change your calls to appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses method to reference MyBaseViewController.

Your current code will affect all instances of UIViewController, including those embedded in Foundation or UIKit. By using your own base class, you are in effect creating a filter that isolates your viewControllers from the others.

Comment: That was actually the thing I was trying to avoid, subclassing all my UIViewControllers as this was currently what I had. Than again, this solution is prettier than my actual implementation as the superclass (BrandedViewController) actually had the method for branding all elements while this still use the appearance, so no loop. Plus no need to reset the UIButton in the UINavigationController. But is there not any other 'selector' for all elements in the actual UIViewController.